# Probing is not working Asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, probing

In my application(ASP.Net2.0),need to group the dlls. So that I used probing ande modified the web.config as follows

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <probing privatePath="bin;../../../Runtime/Satellite"/>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

It is not working in Asp.net2.0. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, probing only works for subdirectories of your app, never in directories "above" you in the tree.

You need to group the DLLs under your app directory (or use the GAC).